# Laravel: How to pass data from form to controller without using Request object

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel, I have logic that is used both by automatic processes and by a user using a web interface.
It gets filtered data from a database table.
There is only 1 filter criteria. I want to use the same method for both purposes.

View

```
            <form action="getJobs" target="_blank" class="mx-4">
                @csrf
                <input type="submit" value="Get Jobs">
                <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                    <option value="">Select a Category</option>
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category}}">{{ $category}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </form>
```

Controller

```
    public function getJobsForCategory($category) {
        //Get all jobs from the database where category=$category
    }

    public function getJobsForCategoryFromBrowser(Request $request) {
        //Get all jobs from the database where category=$request->category
    }
```

Note that the category is not a Model. It's just a string variable.

Is there a way I can pass data from the form to the controller without using the Request object?

Or (the horror), should I fake a Request when using this logic elsewhere in the application, where there is no user interaction?

Every answer I find seems to lead to using the Request object in the Controller.

Comment: try this: in `web.php` -  `Route::get('/something/{test}', function ($test) { dd($test); });` and in your browser:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/something/hello

Answer (score 0):

You should abstract the logic into something like a service class and then call this service class from your HTTP controller and whereever else you want to use it (E.G. command). The service class should not recieve a Request object.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class JobService
{
    public function getJobsForCategory(string $category)
    {
        // Do some business logic
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\JobService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JobController extends BaseController
{
    public function getJobsForCategory(Request $request, JobService $service)
    {
        $jobs = $service->getJobsForCategory($request->category);
        
        // Do some HTTP response
    }
}
```